# Ruby Command Prompt Commands

Tags: ruby, cmd

I am designing a ruby program that needs to run a command and store it a variable.

```
    var = exec('some command');
```

This doesn't work the way I want it to, it just prints the output from the command prompt and then ends the program.
So is there a function that doesn't end the program, doesn't print the cmd output and stores the information in a variable?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use either Ruby's built in backtick syntax, or use `%x`

```
output = `some command`
```

or

```
output = %x(some "command")
```

Answer (score 0):

> Open3 grants you access to stdin, stdout, stderr and a thread to wait
>   the child process when running another program. You can specify
>   various attributes, redirections, current directory, etc., of the
>   program as Process.spawn.

See the various ways of executing a [command](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2012/10/18/backtick-system-exec-in-ruby.html)

Comment: Open3 has a lot of capability, but wading through the documentation would stifle the OPs creativity. Using [`capture2`](http://www.omniref.com/ruby/HEAD/classes/Open3#.capture2), [`capture2e`](http://www.omniref.com/ruby/HEAD/classes/Open3#.capture2e) or [`capture3`](http://www.omniref.com/ruby/HEAD/classes/Open3#.capture3) would be good starting places if not using backticks or `%x` are not friendly enough.